# DB4O doesn't update an Object while adding an object to one of its arguments that is a list of objects

Tags: db4o

i have a object called serie that has 3 args

```
private String name;
    private String picfile;
private Vector<Episode> episodes = new Vector<Episode>();
```

i retrieve  the serie i'm looking for and i add a episode to it

the episode then is added to the serie
but after closing the ObjectContainer and relaunching the program, the serie loose the episode.

hope someone can help.

here's the whole code

```
public class Db4o {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static ObjectContainer db;
static final String path="C:\\Users\\naki\\Documents\\wordmanagement";

public static void afficher(ObjectContainer db)
{
    ObjectSet<Serie> result=db.queryByExample(Serie.class);
    while(result.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(result.next());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO code application logic here

        try{
       // new File(path).delete();
        db=Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), path);
        System.err.println("it's connectetd");
        Serie s1=new Serie();
        s1.setName("Kungfu Panda");

        File file=new File("E:\\Series\\Word pic\\250px-Kung_Fu_Panda_-_Legends_of_Awesomeness_logo.jpg");

        s1.setPicfile(file.toString());
        Episode episode=new Episode();
        episode.setNumbre(4);
        episode.setTitle("The magic Po");
        episode.setSerieName("Kungfu Panda");
        db.store(episode);
        s1.setEpisode(episode);
        db.store(s1);
        ObjectSet<Serie> result=db.queryByExample(new Serie("Kungfu Panda"));
        Serie s=result.next();
        s.setEpisode(episode);

        afficher(db);

        }
        finally
        {
            db.close();
        }

}


public class Serie {
private String name;
    private String picfile;
private Vector<Episode> episodes = new Vector<Episode>();

public String getPicfile() {
    return picfile;
}

public void setPicfile(String picfile) {
    this.picfile = picfile;
}

public Serie(String name) {
   this.name=name; 
}

public Vector<Episode> getEpisodes() {
    return episodes;
}

public void setEpisode(Episode e) {
    this.episodes.add(e);
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Serie{" + "name=" + name + ", picfile=" + picfile + ", episodes=" + episodes + '}';
}


public class Episode {
private int numbre;
private String title;
    private String  serieName;
private ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

public Episode(int numbre, String titl, String  serieName,ArrayList<Word> words) {

    this.numbre = numbre;
    this.title = title;
    this.serieName=serieName;
     this.words = words;
}

public Episode() {

}

public String getSerieName() {
    return serieName;
}

public void setSerieName(String serieName) {
    this.serieName = serieName;
}


public int getNumbre() {
    return numbre;
}

public void setNumbre(int numbre) {
    this.numbre = numbre;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public ArrayList<Word> getWords() {
    return words;
}

public void setWords(ArrayList<Word> words) {
    this.words = words;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" + "Episode=" + numbre + " , title=" + title + '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you might have a problem with update depth (check last part of this blog post):

http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2009/09/db4o-activation-update-depth/

Best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where are you closing and reopening the database.

Anyway, I just run your code (with some changes to reopen the database for instance) and it does retrieve the Serie correctly, meaning, with its episode.

See the code bellow:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.db4o.*;

public class Db4o {

    static final String path = System.getenv("temp") + "\\test.odb";

    public static void afficher(ObjectContainer db) {
        ObjectSet<Serie> result = db.queryByExample(Serie.class);
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(result.next());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        ObjectContainer db = null;
        try {

            new File(path).delete();
            db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), path);
            System.err.println("it's connectetd");

            Serie s1 = new Serie("Kungfu Panda");
            File file = new File(
                    "E:\\Series\\Word pic\\250px-Kung_Fu_Panda_-_Legends_of_Awesomeness_logo.jpg");
            s1.setPicfile(file.toString());

            Episode episode = new Episode(4, "The magic Po", "Kungfu Panda");
            s1.setEpisode(episode);
            db.store(s1);    

            // Reopen the database
            db.close();    
            db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), path);

            afficher(db);

        } finally {
            db.close();
        }

    }
}

class Serie {
    private String name;
    private String picfile;
    private Vector<Episode> episodes = new Vector<Episode>();

    public String getPicfile() {
        return picfile;
    }

    public void setPicfile(String picfile) {
        this.picfile = picfile;
    }

    public Serie(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Vector<Episode> getEpisodes() {
        return episodes;
    }

    public void setEpisode(Episode e) {
        this.episodes.add(e);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Serie{" + "name=" + name + ", picfile=" + picfile
                + ", episodes=" + episodes + '}';
    }
}

class Episode {
    private int numbre;
    private String title;
    private String serieName;

    public Episode(int numbre, String titl, String serieName) {

        this.numbre = numbre;
        this.title = titl;
        this.serieName = serieName;
    }

    public Episode() {

    }

    public String getSerieName() {
        return serieName;
    }

    public void setSerieName(String serieName) {
        this.serieName = serieName;
    }

    public int getNumbre() {
        return numbre;
    }

    public void setNumbre(int numbre) {
        this.numbre = numbre;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "Episode=" + numbre + " , title=" + title + '}';
    }
}
```

Note that on Episode constructor you had an error:

```
public Episode(int numbre, String titl, String serieName) {
    this.numbre = numbre;
    this.title = title; // WRONG. Need to be: this.title = titl;
    this.serieName = serieName;
}
```

Comment: the way i close and reopen is to stop and relaunch the program.

Comment: even if i fixed the episode constructor, i'm still facing the same problem. if i change the serie name it does persist, but if i add an episode to the list of episodes of that serie, it doesn't persist the episode.